# Find number of months and days between two dates in flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I have a task to display remaining months and days for booked cruise. I have tried something but it is not as per the requirements. Future Date is fetch from API and need to compare it with current date to get difference. I have attach image with my tried code.

[image]

DateTime received from API

```
2021-10-05T16:30:00Z
```

Tried Code

```
final date1 = DateTime.now().toUtc();
      final DateTime date2 = DateTime.parse(date).toUtc();

      final difference = date2.difference(date1).inDays;
      final month1 = date1.month.toInt();
      final month2 = date2.month.toInt();
      final monthDiff = month1 - month2;
      final daysDiff = difference - (monthDiff * 30);

      print(difference); 
      print("monthDiff $monthDiff"); 
      print("daysDiff $daysDiff"); 
      return difference.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do. There is a problem that I define `a month` as 30 days.

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  final date1 = DateTime.now();
  final date2 = DateTime.parse('2021-10-05T16:30:00Z');

  final difference = date2.difference(date1);
  final monthDiff = (difference.inDays / 30).floor();
  final daysDiff = difference.inDays % 30;

  print('monthDiff $monthDiff');
  print('daysDiff $daysDiff');
  print(difference);
}
```

Comment: This is working as expected but only issue is of managing 31 days of some months and leap year.

Answer (score 0):

Use the build-in function `difference`:

Taken from the official documentation:

```
var berlinWallFell = DateTime.utc(1989, DateTime.november, 9);
var dDay = DateTime.utc(1944, DateTime.june, 6);

Duration difference = berlinWallFell.difference(dDay);
print(difference.inDays); //here you can use another getter
```

Comment: It shows total number of days between two dates this is not as per requirement.

Comment: @VinayBakle the change it from days to months